# Grub menu doesn't show during boot up

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

I have had ubuntu(currently 18.04) installed alongside windows(8.1) for over a year. 
I was logged into Windows when I closed the lid and after sometime when I came back, "No bootable device found, press any key to reboot" was written on the screen. After reboot, windows opened up and the grub menu didn't appear. So I tried again and it didn't show yet again.

I do not know what is causing the problem or how to deal with it? What should I do?  Is my data on Ubuntu partition lost?

EDIT: Opening boot manager by pressing F12 during boot shows these 4 options under " UEFI Boot" panel:

- UEFI OnBoard LAN IPv4
- UEFI OnBoard LAN IPv6
- Windows Boot Manager
- Ubuntu

Selecting Ubuntu option invokes the normal boot sequence and the grub menu appears. But this doesn't persists after reboot and boot directly advances to Windows. How do I make this permanent?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a live usb with ubuntu or anything like that, and run grub-install and update-grub in terminal, then if everything goes right you will see the grub boot menu.